# Script to install and activate backports on debian squeeze?

Tags: debian, apt, debian-squeeze

I am looking for a script that would enable debian backports for debian squeeze, something that I could just run and will enable me to install new packages like a decent version of mercurial after, just by doing `apt-get upgrade mercurial`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) and put the instructions there in a script. What's the problem with it?

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "deb http://YOURMIRROR.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports(-sloppy) main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
```

And then you can do

```
 apt-get -t squeeze-backports install "mercurial"
```

Comment: Is there a way to activate mercurial from backports so you can install it without having to specify the `-t` ?